# The same left and right labels on every tree node - TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I'm am trying to form a tree where every node has a '(' before the node and a ')' after the node. I understand that this is achievable through something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
        every node/.style = {shape=circle, draw, align=center}]]
    \node[label={left:(}, label={right:)}] {}
    child { node[label={left:(}, label={right:)}] {} }
    child { node[label={left:(}, label={right:)}] {}
            child { node[label={left:(}, label={right:)}] {}
                    child { node[label={left:(}, label={right:)}] {} }
                    child { node[label={left:(}, label={right:)}] {} }
                    child { node[label={left:(}, label={right:)}] {} } }
            child { node[label={left:(}, label={right:)}] {} } };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Giving the following result:

[image]

However, this is not ideal and I would rather not have to copy and paste the same code each time (something something maintainability). I have tried placing the label code within the node style, however that doesn't seem to be supported. I have tried to find a way to create a custom node to which I can assign labels, but I also have struggled to get something like that working / haven't been able to find anything on it.

For context, I am trying to display a tree representation of a Dyck word where the pre and post numbers after performing DFS represent the indices of '(' and ')'.

Desired code form:

```latex
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
            every node/.style = {shape=circle, draw, align=center}]] % <-- some style here for the ()?
        \node {}
        child { node {} }
        child { node {}
                child { node {}
                        child { node {} }
                        child { node {} }
                        child { node {} } }
                child { node {} } };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `execute at begin node={(},execute at end node={)}` ? You can make this a style that you contains these keys.

Comment: This unfortunately places the ( and ) inside the nodes rather than a label to the left of the node and a label to the right of the node

Comment: Well, this is the reason why one should always add a compilable complete code. You could set the `inner xsep` to a negative value, then the parentheses will be outside. Or you make the labels a style.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the code it can easily be compiled and also given the desired output. Setting the `inner xsep` to a negative value only increases the node size, not the location of the brackets

Comment: @Hive7, to be easily compiled the code must start with `\documentclass...`, load all the necessary libraries/packages, and end with `\end{document}`...: so that we can simply "copy and paste" it into my editor and press "compile".

Comment: Ah sorry, updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with `every node` is that this style gets applied to labels, which are nodes as well, thus creating an infinite recursion. Use `every child node` instead. This style is designed to get only applied to the, well, child nodes but not the labels.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
        ears/.style={shape=circle, draw, align=center,
            label={left:(}, label={right:)}},
        every child node/.style = {ears}]]
    \node[ears] {}
    child { node {} }
    child { node {}
            child { node {}
                    child { node {} }
                    child { node {} }
                    child { node {} } }
            child { node {} } };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, setting label in the `every node/.style` does not work, however, creating a new node style does seem to. The following code produces the desired results:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{dyck/.style={
    draw,
    circle,
    label={left:(},
    label={right:)},
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
        every node/.style = {shape=circle, draw, align=center}]]
    \node[dyck] {}
    child { node[dyck] {} }
    child { node[dyck] {}
            child { node[dyck] {}
                    child { node[dyck] {} }
                    child { node[dyck] {} }
                    child { node[dyck] {} } }
            child { node[dyck] {} } };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is really weird. Even when creating a node style and applying it to every node in the tikzpicture declaration won't work... Anyway, your solution is better than copy/paste the labeling on every node.

Comment: The reason why `every node/.style` does not work is that this gets applied to labels, which are also nodes, to you will produce an infinite recursion.

Comment: It definitely makes sense. It was indeed a capacity exceeded error.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, that makes sense!